# I don't understand jQuery.data() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

`.data()-Attaches` data to, or gets data from, selected elements. A method in jQuery

Question:

1) What the purpose of this method ?
2) When I run it, I see NO data-* attribute created. So what is the difference between `data-*` attribute and data created by `data()` method in jQuery?

```
<!--code from w3school -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("div").data("greeting", "Hello World");
  });
  $("#btn2").click(function(){
    alert($("div").data("greeting"));
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="btn1">Attach data to div element</button><br>
<button id="btn2">Get data attached to div element</button>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `.data()` method *never* creates `data-` attributes. It will *read* from them, but it does not add them to elements.

Answer (score 1):

One use case can be around storing instance, pseudo code below

```
function SomePlugin(element, options) {
    this.$el = $(element);
    this.options = options;
}

SomePlugin.prototype.method = function() {
    this.$el.toggleClass(this.options.cssClass);
}

$.fn.somePlugin = function(options) {
    var somePluginInstance = new SomePlugin(this, options);
    // store instance as data
    this.data("somePlugin", somePluginInstance);
}
```

usage:

```
$(".element").somePlugin({});

var pluginInstance = $(".element").data("somePlugin");

pluginInstance.method();
```

Answer (score 1):

The .data() method allow you to attach data of any type of DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

We can set several distinct values for a single element and retrieve them later: (Documentation example)

```
$( "body" ).data( "foo", 52 );
$( "body" ).data( "bar", { isManual: true } );
$( "body" ).data( { baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] } );
$( "body" ).data( "foo" ); // 52
$( "body" ).data(); // { foo: 52, bar: { isManual: true }, baz: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

"Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.

Prior to jQuery 1.4.3, .data( obj ) completely replaced all data. Since jQuery 1.4.3, data is instead extended by shallow merge."

font: jquery documentation

:)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding HTML5 data-* attributes: This low-level method does NOT retrieve the data-* attributes unless the more convenient .data() method has already retrieved them.

The jQuery.data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks. We can retrieve several distinct values for a single element one at a time, or as a set.

You can refer this [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) for more details. I hope this can help you.